WordPress/MySQL Upgrade from 5.74.4 to 5.78.0 hangs on Upgrade DB to 5.78.beta1: SQL
First time this has happened for me. Doing a periodic update, going from civicrm 5.74.4 to 5.78.0, the upgrade process seems to have hung on "Upgrade DB to 5.78.beta1: SQL".
Last few lines of the CiviCRM log:
2024-10-06 08:56:42-0400  [info] Running task: Upgrade DB to 5.78.alpha1: SQL
2024-10-06 08:56:43-0400  [info] Running task: Finish Upgrade DB to 5.78.alpha1
2024-10-06 08:56:43-0400  [info] Running task: Begin Upgrade to 5.78.beta1
2024-10-06 08:56:44-0400  [info] Running task: Upgrade DB to 5.78.beta1
2024-10-06 08:56:45-0400  [info] Running task: Upgrade DB to 5.78.beta1: SQL
It's been stuck there for over 10 minutes. Can't find any error message in any other logs.
The site is working, for the few tests I've done on it... but... this is worrisome. Would rather not do a full rollback.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.
Michael

Based on the contents of .../civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/sql/5.78.beta1.mysql.tpl and the empty 5.78.alpha1.mysql.tpl file, at least assuming the comments on the columns were not that way before already, it looks like that part completed.

The comments were like that before. What you'd want to compare is if the column specifies not null. You can also manually run each line and see where it hangs. The statements are re-runnable so you wouldn't need to restore.

Thanks. I ran all of the statements in that file and they all worked fine. Beginning to think the failure was the task failed to add / execute. And assuming this is the entire process and that was the last step, what else has to be done to mark the update as complete so I can do a future update?

There are a few more steps where it does stuff with extensions and message templates. What I'd try is running UPDATE civicrm_domain SET version='5.77.0' and then re-run the upgrade.

That produced a successful update message. Thanks!
